# Concurrent background file uploads like google drive

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, file-upload, next.js

I have a HTML/CSS/JS SPA where you have a bunch of users and a list of their actions that can be filtered and viewed by user or date. Each of those actions can have large videos associated to it.
I am looking to implement a file upload for each of those action entries such that once I queue an upload, then I can switch to another user or date or action and the upload would still keep going. I was thinking of something like Google Drive's upload feature where once you start the upload a progress bar shows up where you can track progress of all your uploads.

Any recommended way to do this ? I would preferably want to slap in a React component to handle the uploads in there instead of plain js/html/css. I have used Uppy.io before and it looks like a great tool to handle upload but am not sure if it can handle this sort of upload feature.

Note: our backend is .NET 4.6.1 in c#

Comment: Does [slice upload](https://gist.github.com/ve3/9bc4ec3ee9bcce755c23bddbfce33306) meet your requirement?

Comment: Looks like slice upload breaks a large upload into smaller chunks. I am looking to run multiple large file uploads on my SPA at the same time. Basically I want to be able to use the UI while multiple uploads are queued and running in the background.